# Communication between website and windows

Tags: windows, powershell, web

This is general question, how to approach this problem.

For my technical degree i would like to do sort of website application that will connect windows machine, send a request to powershell e.g. get-processes, and in the end display it on the website.

I'm not sure if PowerShell Web Access can be modified like that, Is there any other solution?

Like service that i could communicate on?

-mateusz

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell runspaces, this is an example, but in your case you might have to change it for the authentication methods in you have to use...

```
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(user, secure_pw);

WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Credssp;
connectionInfo.ProxyAuthentication = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;
connectionInfo.OperationTimeout = 4 * 60 * 1000; // 4 minutes.
connectionInfo.OpenTimeout = 1 * 60 * 1000; // 1 minute.
connectionInfo.Credential = credential;

Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

rs.Open();
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    string hostname = "my-host";
    PowerShellInstance.Runspace = rs;
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(string.Format("param([string]$hostname) Get-Process -ComputerName $hostname"))
    PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("hostname", hostname);

    // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

    // do something with the errors found.
    if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var error in PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Exception.Message);
        }
    }
}

rs.Dispose();
```

If do it this way, I recommend you do a bit of research about PowerShellInstance.AddScript vs PowerShellInstance.AddCommand and how the parameters have to be handled, etc...